# How to add actionBarSize padding in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In xml we used to get actionBarSize using ?actionBarSize, how do I get the same when using Jetpack Compose. I want to add padding to a composable same as actionBarSize.

Modifier.navigationBarsPadding() doesn't worked for me

Comment: can you share more detail and exactly how you want to get?

Answer (score 2):

in compose you use topBar within a Scaffold
you can modify the TopAppBar in the topbar to get your bar padding

```
@Composable
fun YourComposableScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "title"))
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp) 
            )
        }
    ) {
        // content
    }
}
```